# Matalab ODE with bad result

Tags: matlab

> > syms y(t) yef(t);
> > ymax=120*0.40680;
> > yef(t)= 0.95*(1/(1+(y(t)/ymax)*y(t)+(1-(1/(1+(y(t)/ymax))*ymax))));
> > yo=0.40680*140;
> > k10=2.37;
> > R=0.00831447;
> > T=395;
> > HA=0.08;
> > n1=1.51;
> > E1=83.3;
> > K1=k10*(10^10)*(HA^n1)*exp(-E1/R*T);
> > ode=diff(y(t),t)==-K1*yef(t);
> > cond=y(0)==yo;
> > ySol(t)=dsolve(ode,cond)

ySol(t) =

7119/125

Why i get this result? what im doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why $K1yef(t)$ is not $K1*yef(t)$ ?

Comment: Please format your post so it is more readable.